# Apply style to an element of class if href exists for another element in css

Tags: css

I have a following condition:

```
<div>
    <h2>Without link</h2>
    <img src="some link"/>
</div>

<div>
    <h2><a href="#">With link</a></h2>
    <img src="some other link"/>
</div>
```

I have to apply style on every img tag if its sibling h2 has a link in it. Can it be done using css only?

Comment: You need to traverse the parent element, which is currently not possible using CSS alone. You may try other JavaScript fixes.

Comment: Not with css only. Also the duplicate is wrong. This isn't about selecting the parent.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I agree with Phiter, it's maybe impossible but the duplicate is not relevant .. at least for the OP

Comment: @Phiter and Temani, I would argue against. The OP has to select the parent from `<a>` to select the `h2` and then select the sibling `img`.

Comment: He has to, but that's not what he asked for